# clean dataframe by columns condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I would like to keep only the rows of a `Dataframe` with the following condition: the intervals(included) in which the beginning condition is `col1 = 0, col2 = 1` and the interval end `col1 = 0, col2 = 2`.

## Sample data

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'id':['id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id2','id2']
                  ,'col1':[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],'col2':[1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2]})
```

## This would look like this:

```
    col1 col2 id
0   0   1   id1
1   1   2   id1
2   1   2   id1
3   0   1   id1
4   1   2   id1
5   0   2   id1
6   0   1   id1
7   1   2   id1
8   1   2   id1
9   0   2   id1
10  0   1   id1
11  1   2   id2
12  0   2   id2
13  0   1   id2
14  1   2   id2
15  1   2   id2
```

## Output Sample

We can realise that there are only "blocks" or intervals with `0-1,0-2` in `col1,col2`.

```
   col1 col2 id
3   0   1   id1
4   1   2   id1
5   0   2   id1
6   0   1   id1
7   1   2   id1
8   1   2   id1
9   0   2   id1
10  0   1   id1
11  1   2   id2
12  0   2   id2
```

As a result rows 0,1,2,13,14,15 were erased because they weren't a in a 0-1 , 0-2 interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the new para `group` (drop it by using `df.drop('group',1)`)

---

Setting up

```
df['group']=(df.col1==0)&(df.col2==1)
df['group']=df['group'].cumsum()
```

---

Option1

```
mask=df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x : sum((x.col1==0)&(x.col2==2)))
df.loc[df.group.isin(mask[mask.eq(1)].index)]


Out[363]: 
    col1  col2   id  group
3      0     1  id1      2
4      1     2  id1      2
5      0     2  id1      2
6      0     1  id1      3
7      1     2  id1      3
8      1     2  id1      3
9      0     2  id1      3
10     0     1  id1      4
11     1     2  id2      4
12     0     2  id2      4
```

---

Option2 case mention by
@Bharathshetty

```
mask=df.groupby('group').last().loc[lambda x : (x.col1==0)&(x.col2==2),].index
df.loc[df.group.isin(mask)]


Out[379]: 
    col1  col2   id  group
3      0     1  id1      2
4      1     2  id1      2
5      0     2  id1      2
6      0     1  id1      3
7      1     2  id1      3
8      1     2  id1      3
9      0     2  id1      3
10     0     1  id1      4
11     1     2  id2      4
12     0     2  id2      4
```

Comment: check if third row is `3     1     1  id1` instead of 0. Op wants the group if it starts with `(0,1)` and end in `(0,2)`

Comment: @Bharathshetty sorry I can not get it .. can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: Check with this data
`df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id2','id2']
                  ,'col1':[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],'col2':[1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2]})`

Comment: @Bharathshetty for the case your mention , I think it will belong to the first group 1   rather than a new group 2

Comment: what about if in some id the (0,2)  are missing?. I meant group by (0,1- 0,2) but in the case of (0-2) is missing group it also in order to keep it in the data base. i.e: rows in the data sample(0 ,1 ,2).

Comment: @PeCaDe can you show your data ? and expected out put again , it is hard to clarify it ..

Comment: I would open new question in order to have another target. thanks a lot @Wen